# Python: How to convert an image folder into a dataset containing features and labels?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am using Python 2.7 with sklearn, skimage and OpenCV.

I want to convert a folder of images into a .mat image dataset containing features and labels. On the dataset, I will use the HOG descriptor for feature extraction. I am trying to access the image folder using the following code:

`from sklearn import datasets`

`dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata("C:\\Users\\local.user\\Desktop\\image-folder")`

But how to create a **.mat** image dataset using Python which contains a feature-label pair for each image ?

Comment: You can use ``from skimage.io import imread_collection`` to load the images, and ``from skimage.feature import hog`` to create the HOG descriptor.  To save to a MATLAB file, you'll need ``from scipy.io import savemat``.

Comment: @Stefan: I tried imread_collection(), it says "No suitable plugin registered for imread collection". How to register a suitable plugin ?

Comment: What kinds of files are you trying to load?

Comment: I am loading .jpg files.

Comment: Do you have matplotlib installed?

Comment: Yeah, Matplotlib is installed and plt.show() works, but imread_collection() is not working.

Comment: Can you try: ``import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.imread(filename)``.

Comment: plt.imread() is working. It displays the array values.

Comment: I typed `io.use_plugin('test','imread_collection'); skimage.io.imread_collection('C:\\Users\\local.user\\Desktop\\IMG.jpg')`.It says `assert conserve_memory==False    AssertionError`

Comment: Can you try: `skimage.io.imread_collection(':\\Users\\local.user\\Desktop\\IMG.jpg', plugin='matplotlib')` ?  Also, this might be easier to debug on https://gitter.im/scikit-image/scikit-image

Comment: I tried the code. Getting `RuntimeError: Could not find the plugin "matplotlib" for imread_collection.`

Comment: What version of scikit-image are you running?

Comment: The scikit-image version installed is 0.7.2-1

Comment: That's an ancient version--please upgrade to 0.11.

Comment: Ok, I'll upgrade it.

Comment: Now _imread_collection_ works with the following code:
`os.chdir('/home/local-user/Desktop/image-folder'); io.use_plugin('test','imread_collection'); collection1 = imread_collection('*.png', conserve_memory=False, plugin='test');`. _HOG descriptors_ can be extracted from an individual image. But how to extract them from _imread_collection_ ?

Comment: `out = []; for img in img_collection: out.append(some_func(img))`

Comment: Although _imread_collection_ works, when the type of _img_collection_ object is printed, it returns NoneType. Here is the code:
`os.chdir('/home/local-user/Desktop/image-folder');
collection1 = imread_collection('*.png',conserve_memory=False,plugin='test');
type(collection1);`

The output obtained is **<type 'NoneType'>**. Why ?

Comment: I also tried scikit-image 0.11.3-9 on WIndows. 
`type(imread_collection_obj)` is displayed as **<type 'NoneType'>**.
What could be the reason ?

Comment: The 'test' plugin won't work to load images.  Try 'matplotlib' instead.

Comment: 'matplotlib' works with 'imread', but not with 'imread_collection'.

Comment: Please bring your question to the mailing list.  I think SO is probably not the right forum to explore your problem.